# Any way to get Processing working in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, processing

Is there any convenient way to get the Processing language working in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

Haven't used VS much, but do check out this [great answer on the Best Java IDE for VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605215/best-java-ide-for-visual-studio-fan).

I am not fully aware of your setup/needs, but I would say, if Processing is must and you don't find the 'Processing IDE' usable, use **eclipse**.
If you need to use bits and bobs that Processing has to offer, why not try [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/), which is [C++](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/vs-2008) and is very similar to Processing.

[image: OF logo]

Depending on your needs, might be worth having a quick look at [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/) or [Polycode](http://polycode.org/) which are C++ also. Personally I think OpenFrameworks is the closest to Processing and it's fairly easy to port code from Processing to it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the links. Lots of interesting stuff! In taking a class that's using Processing, and I'm a hardcore C# fanboy. Trying to get the best of both.

Comment: Glad it helps. It depends on the purpose of things. From my point of view, easiest way to do Processing with a proper IDE is with eclipse+[proclipsing](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/)